# How do I programmatically mount zfs at boot?

Tags: boot, command-line, hard-drive, password, encryption

I encrypted my hard drive with zfs, running ubuntu 22.04.

I'm an idiot and forgot my password. However, I'm pretty confident that it is contained in a list of ~300 passwords that I know.

When I boot, I see a field to enter password, with text under it saying "Please unlock disk keystore-rpool"

Problem is, I only get 3 attempts at the password before the maximum number of attempts is reached. After I fail 3 times, I see a terminal with the error:

```
command: mount -o zfsutil -t zfs rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_{redacted} /root//
message: zfs_mount_at() failed: encryption key not loadedzfs_mount_at() failed: encryption key not loadedmount: mounting rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_{redacted} on /root// failed: Permission denied
Error: 2

Failed to mount rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_{redacted} on /root//.
Manually mount the filesystem and exit
```

And the user in the terminal is (initramfs).

When I try to run the `zfs_mount_at() failed: encryption key not loaded` command in this terminal, I immediately get the following same error as in the message above.

At this point I get stuck and am forced to hard reboot.

My question is: can I  write a script to programmatically try 3 passwords from the list, wait until I can try again (not sure how to set the wait part up, currently I have to manually hard reboot), and try the next 3, until the password succeeds?

Any help would be greatly appreciated here, the hard drive is pretty important, and I learned this lesson the hard way.

Comment: I'd like to know that as well. If you are to lazy to push the button you can at least `reboot -f`` ;)